# How to determine exit status of certain libc functions?

Tags: c, function, libc

1) In libc there are certain functions which return just
the exit status - success status and error status(es).

2) There are other functions that return a usable value. How do
they communicate their exit status to the user?
There are two options:

2.1) return non-used value to signal success status
and another non-used return value to signal that error
happened and its status must be looked in "errno" variable.

2.2) return only **one** non-used
value to signal the user that the exit status must be looked
in "errno" variable.

In sub-case 2.2) there is the problem: success status is not set
in "errno" variable, only error status(es).

Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but it is not clear to me
which logic must be used to sanely use such functions.

For example, `readdir()` or `getwchar()`.

An example follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>

int main(void)
{
  DIR *dp;
  struct dirent *ep;
  if ((dp = opendir("/tmp/")) == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "opendir: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    exit(-1);
  }
  errno = EINVAL; /* suppose some function exited with error earlier */
  while ((ep = readdir(dp)) != NULL) {
    if (strcmp(ep->d_name, ".") == 0
     || strcmp(ep->d_name, "..") == 0)
        continue;
    printf("%s\n",ep->d_name);
  }
  if (errno != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "readdir: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    closedir(dp);
    exit(-1);
  }
  closedir(dp);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
...
readdir: Invalid argument
```

Comment: @ShawnicHedgehog How to do this **within** the program?

Comment: @ShawnicHedgehog: That has nothing to do with the question and libc functions.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. The functions are well documented, including their return values - which you seem to be aware of. As asked now, your question already states the answer clearly.

Comment: `readdir` is not a standard C function. Please specify which platform or which additional standard you use.

Comment: @Olaf `readdir()` may not be a standard C function, but `getwchar()` is... (I'm using GNU libc on Debian 9). nnn's answer is helpful, but does not explain the logic behind this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can read from the POSIX specification of `readdir`
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/readdir_r.html

> When an error is encountered, a null pointer shall be returned and
>   *errno* shall be set to indicate the error. When the end of the
>   directory is encountered, a null pointer shall be returned and *errno*
>   is not changed.

You should do this

```
errno = 0;
```

before every call to `readdir`. Then you can know for sure if an error occurred (and *errno* was set appropriately) or it naturally returned null for *end of directory*.

You can find this trick being used on the example at the above link.

Comment: `do ... if ... while` trick sort of makes the job, but it is a kludge (just `while ...` would be much more natural). Still, I do not understand the rationale behind the decision not to set `errno` on success.

Answer (score 2):

What you've run into is a bit of a hole in the specification for `readdir()`. There is no distinction made between returning NULL at the end of a directory listing and returning NULL on error:

> The `readdir()` function returns a pointer to the next directory entry.  It
>   returns NULL upon reaching the end of the directory or on error.  In the
>   event of an error, `errno` may be set to any of the values documented for
>   the `getdirentries(2)` system call.

In practice, it's safe to assume that `readdir()` never returns an error, and that a NULL return value always means that you have reached the end of the directory. There are very few practical situations that will lead to `opendir()` succeeding but a subsequent `readdir()` failing, and most such situations are non-recoverable anyways. (The most likely cause is a sudden failure of a storage device.)

Comment: But we cannot always be sure that, for example, `getwc()` always gets valid input. The question is general, `readdir()` was just an example.

Comment: @IgorLiferenko For `getwc()`, you can use `feof()` or `ferror()` to determine what happened after the fact. `readdir()` is an exception, as directory streams don't support any of the normal utilities available on file streams.

Comment: (As an aside, I'd like to point out that the entire wide-character API is an ill-thought-out mess. But that's not the issue at hand here.)

Comment: (For the record: wide-character API is well-thought-out, having been designed with the benefit of hindsight. On the contrary, `char` API is ill-thought-out mess.)